# Open specific class rather than bean definition when clicked ref definition of spring-context.xml

Tags: xml, spring, intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

My **`spring-context.xml`**

```
<bean id="aBean" class="com.example.A">
    <constructor-arg ref="bBean"/>
</bean>

<bean id="bBean" class="com.example.B">
    <!-- Properties -->
</bean>
```

Lets say I have two beans on **`spring-context.xml`** file. Here **bBean** is injected to **aBean** using `constructor`. I'm using well known **`ref`** attribute to inject the **bBean**.

When I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>Click</kbd>  on `bBean` my mouse mouse cursor moves to bean definition of of `bBean` on XML.

How can I open the class **`com.example.B`** when I click `bBean` of `<constructor-arg ref="bBean"/>.` Any **shortcut key** that I'm unaware of.

Using **`IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2 Ultimate`**

Comment: Are you using the community edition or ultimate?  If ultimate, you might see a small icon in the margin next to the bean definition that you can use to navigate to the code, and one in the code to navigate back to the config file.

Comment: I'm using Ultimate. I want to go from xml ref definition to Class directly

Comment: I guess they didn't feel the need to let you navigate from the bean id because you can ctrl-click on the class attribute to navigate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I found the answer

You can click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> to directly to class when you click the bean defined by `ref`

Action name is **`Type Declaration`**

[image]